# Java fileinputstream No such file or directory

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I'm trying to learn how to use read line by line from a text file. Even though I put the txt file in the same src, the console always shows the error as - `No such file or directory`.

```
public class ddd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("/dd/src/com/dd/input.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        System.out
                .println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

}[image]

Comment: I might recommend using the current working directory System.getProperty("user.dir")) to find out where you are currently working. That proved to be one of the biggest issues I had when learning to use file input/output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
"/dd/src/com/dd/input.txt"
```

On Linux at least, this would be an *absolute* path. What you probably want instead is a path relative to the project root:

```
"src/com/dd/input.txt"
```

Or, if you're packaging this file into your program, use a resource stream instead of a raw `FileInputStream`:

```
InputStream is = ddd.class.getResourceAsStream("input.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative path e.g. `"src/com/dd/input.txt"`. I tried and it's working fine.

> Output

```
Reading File line by line using BufferedReader
hhhh
```

My `input.txt` has **hhhh** content.